# How do I keep an initial field value in a Django form

Tags: django, django-forms

In my django form I have an object_id that is a hidden UUIDField:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    object_id = forms.UUIDField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

In my view, I populate this id field with an initial value.

```
form = MyForm(initial={'object_id': pk,})
```

The idea is that I pass a primary key to the form and then get it back again when the for is submitted. That works. But what if the user tampers with the hidden field?

To prevent this I set **disabled=True** on my object_id, which according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) means that the initial value should be respected (although perhaps this only means an initial value defined on the field, rather than one defined on the form, through the view?).

Unfortunately the result is that now my object_id returns a None object.

So the question is, should disabling a field mean that it doesn't return a value. If it does, is there any way to ensure that a hidden value does a safe round trip through a submitted form?

Comment: The common Django way is to use a [django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) and have the object pk as part if the URL. Maybe this doesn't work for you, but I thought I should mention it if you missed it.

Comment: Thanks Tomas. That's certainly an option, but I'm trying to work out this from first principles. It is interesting that they send the pk as an URL parameter.